# How to change payment methods background on woocommerce

Tags: css, woocommerce

I want to change the background of the order summary and payment methods (Woocommerce). The CSS code below changes the order summary. However, the background color of the following payment methods section does not change. I could not write the CSS.

The constant part is inspect `ul.wc_payment_methods.payment_methods.methods`.

```
.woocommerce-checkout table.shop_table {
    background-color: #fff;   
}
```

Comment: Send me the link to your site.

Comment: Where are you adding it? Child theme? Try using this - `#order_review .woocommerce-checkout table.shop_table`

Comment: I'm adding it with additional CSS/parent theme ? Also I couldn't get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override two elements. `#order_review` is added so that the specificity of custom CSS is higher.

```css
#order_review .woocommerce-checkout #payment ul.payment_methods, /* Payment Method */
#order_review table.woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table { /* Review Order */
  background: #fff;
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Edit:

There was a response from support. Also need to be added CSS code:

```
.woocommerce-checkout #payment .wc_payment_methods {    
   background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am very sad. I am very bad at design. I've added these codes to the additional CSS, but the current part is still gray (payment methods). Should I do something else?

Comment: I am not sure about the problem until I see the backend. From the frontend, I don't see that you have applied the code. Are you following this documentation? https://docs.drfuri.com/martfury/3-how-to-add-your-custom-css/ It could also be that you are using a cache plugin.

Comment: Thank you again for your attention. Yes, I am adding the code in the same way. I hadn't published the code because it didn't work. Now the code page has been published(...)

Comment: I am using the WP Fastest Cache plugin and I have disabled it now. However, nothing changed.

Comment: If it works from me through the frontend, the code should work for you too. I have no idea what is it unless I see the backend. Because there can be some other factors affecting the code.

Comment: Thank you again @m4n0. The problem is resolved and I added it to the thread.